# Running A Javascript command through Browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

Through Java, I am trying to click a link on a jsp webpage.

However, when I tried to click the link through xpath and other means, it didn't work...
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Member")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Member')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul[2]/li/a")).click();

When I highlight the link text, I see this;
javascript:sendTo('/mp/secure/proxy/MemberSelect.do?event=FirstTime')

Is there a way to have the webdriver just run this command, instead of trying to click on the link?

Any help is appreciated! I am way out of my league and I am just trying to achieve something simple...

Answer (score 0):

this is a Jquery expression you can try with. 
try (JscriptExecutor(driver)).ExecuteScript("$("a:contains(Member)").click();");
To know more about how to use jQuery in your Automation Code, refer the link:http://yuvarajatcts.blogspot.com/2014/07/coded-ui-jquery-selectors.html

Comment: Hmm... Can you give example?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's hard to get Selenium/WebDriver to behave when using XPath notation.  I find that I can write much more stable and readable tests using CSS selectors.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('table ul a')).click();
```

Ideally, you'd give your element a specific class name or ID so that you're relying less on the document structure to find the element.

You might even be able to use the `href` of the link as an identifier if you're lucky with something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('a[href*="thingy"]')).click();
```

... to match a link with the following HTML, for example:

```
<a href="http://example.com/stuff/thingy/foo/bar">Member Link</a>
```

Comment: I didn't make the webpage. Are you saying assign it in the code?

Comment: I was basically saying that if the HTML element (i.e., the anchor tag of the link you're trying to click) contains something that identifies it uniquely then you can use that as a reference.  If you haven't got control over the HTML then obviously you can't assign the ID yourself.  You might be able to use the href, though.